# Hide and Show WinJS.UI.PivotItem

Tags: javascript, css, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, winjs

I need to hide a `WinJS.UI.PivotItem` for a Windows Phone 8.1 app and then show it again once certain criteria have been met.

I thought it would be as simple as using CSS to show and hide the `WinJS.UI.PivotItem`, but it hides the `.win-pivot-item` element but not the `.win-pivot-header`?

How can I programmatically show and hide a `WinJS.UI.PivotItem` in a `WinJS.UI.Pivot` control?

```
<div id="divContent" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.Pivot" data-win-options="{title: 'Details', selectedIndex: 0}">
    <div id="divSelected" style="display: none;" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.PivotItem" data-win-options="{'header': 'Currently Selected'}">

        <!-- Content - Hide this until we need it -->

    </div>
    <div id="divSelections" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.PivotItem" data-win-options="{'header': 'Selections'}">

        <!-- Content -->

    </div>
    <div id="divInformation" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.PivotItem" data-win-options="{'header': 'Other Information'}">

        <!-- Content -->

    </div>
    <div id="divHistory" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.PivotItem" data-win-options="{'header': 'History'}">

        <!-- Content -->

    </div>
    <div id="divDetails" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.PivotItem" data-win-options="{'header': 'Details'}">

        <!-- Content -->

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There currently isn't a direct API to show/hide `WinJS.UI.PivotItems` on the `WinJS.UI.Pivot` control.

Depending on your desired UX and criteria for show/hiding, you can programmatically add/remove a `PivotItem` from the list of `PivotItems` returned by the `Pivot.items` property on the `WinJS.UI.Pivot`control.

For example:

```
    function createPivotElement() {
        // Use document.createElement("div") to build up the DOM for the Pivot Item
        // Or you could render a page using the WinJS.UI.Pages API

        // Return a DOM element
        return document.createElement('div');
    }

    // When criteria is met...
    // Find the pivot in the DOM
    var p = document.querySelector(".myPivot");
    var pivot = p.winControl;


    var element = createPivotElement();
    var pivotItem = new WinJS.UI.PivotItem(element, { header: 'New PivotItem' });

    // Add new PivotItem
    // You could use other things like splice to add it to a specific index etc.
    pivot.items.push(pivotItem);
```

You can also look at the [Pivot Sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/HTML-Pivot-control-sample-3d99f58c) or on http://try.buildwinjs.com/#pivot for more usage examples